# On hover append circle on top of hovered circle in D3 v5

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to append a circle on mouse hover on the existing circle in D3 but not sure how to achieve the coordinates of a hovered circle and append new circle on top of it and remove it on mouse out.

mouse hover on green circle should display blue circle around it.
[image: mouse hover on green circle should display blue circle around it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, put the green circle in a `g` element and attach listener to that element, which adds and removes the outer circle on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` respectively.

I've thrown together a JSFiddle demoing it: https://jsfiddle.net/df23r1yj/

First append a `g` element for each data element (setting [`pointer-events` to `all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) makes it trigger events even when elements have no fill):

```
const circleG = svg.append('g')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(data).enter()
  .append('g')
  .style('pointer-events', 'all')
```

Add a green circle for each data element:

```
circleG.append('circle')
  .classed('persistentCircle', true)
  .attr('cx', (d) => { return d.x })
  .attr('cy', (d) => { return d.y })
  .attr('r', (d) => { return d.r })
  .style('stroke', 'green')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('fill', 'black')
  .style('fill-opacity', 0)
```

Adding event listeners that append and remove the outer blue circle. Using `insert` instead of the conventional `append` puts the outer circle behind the inner circle. Giving the outer circle a class - `removeableCircle` - makes it easy to remove it on mouseleave.:

```
circleG
  .on('mouseenter', function () {
    d3.select(this)
      .insert('circle', ':first-child')
      .classed('removeableCircle', true)
      .attr('cx', (d) => { return d.x })
      .attr('cy', (d) => { return d.y })
      .attr('r', (d) => { return d.r * 1.5 })
      .style('stroke', 'blue')
      .style('fill', 'none')
      .style('pointer-events', 'none')
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function () {
    d3.select(this).selectAll('.removeableCircle').remove()
  })
```

Hope this helps!